# ComboBox values assign to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

Hi guys Iwant to assign a combobox value to stored procedure to insert data into a table

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
```

When am assign to `MessageBox`

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

System.Data.DataRowView
```

But it shows error like

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Can y explain wt is the problem.

Comment: I believe if you add a parameter of type VARCHAR and you fail to define a length explicitly, that length will default to **1 character** - if you happen to attempt to insert more than that 1 single character, you get this error....

Answer (score 2):

Error Message:

String or binary data would be truncated.

Severity level:
16.

Description:
**This error message appears when you try to insert a string with more characters than the column can maximal accommodate.**

copied from here: [String or binary data would be truncated](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/string-or-binary-data-truncated/)

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you do this:

```
string title = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("post_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
parameter.Size = title.Length;
parameter.Value = title ;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

The error is telling you that you have reach the upper limit of the Varchar. By default, the varchar will take the size of the string.